# How to make Primary Key for Weak Entity

Tags: database-design, foreign-keys, primary-key, composite-primary-key

I have a `Course` entity for my college database.
The schema is as follows:

```
Course(name, department, section, semester, teacher_id, college_id)
```

It is a weak entity with `College` as its owner entity. (Primary key for college is `college_id` which is stored as the `foreign key`)

My question is... How do I form the primary key for `Course`?

I mean, technically I *could* make a composite primary key out of *all* the attributes of `Course` but if I have to reference *this* composite primary key as a foreign key in some other table, that would be a huge headache. Or would it? Is there any alternate ways I could acheive the same?

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Weak entities necessarily have composite primary keys, and referencing those weak entities in relationships will involve composite foreign keys. If you think that's a headache, you can introduce a surrogate key which will turn it into a regular entity.

A surrogate key is simply a new identifying attribute. For example you could add a `course_id` attribute which can be implemented as an autoincrement column in the `Course` table.

When introducing surrogate keys, take care to declare unique constraints for any other candidate keys (such as the composite key you would've used before introducing the surrogate key).

Comment: Thank you so much. But can you please explain how do I make this surrogate key? I mean is there any particular way/ theory I should know? Can you please kindly link me to some resource?

Comment: I added an explanation to my answer. For in depth discussion, I suggest you get a good university textbook. There are many online resources but few that understand and convey the concepts accurately.

Comment: One of my favorite introductions to database theory is `Applied mathematics for database professionals` by Toon Koppelaars and Lex de Haan. I also like Bill Kent's `Data and reality`, and C.J. Date's `Introduction to database systems` (which actually has a lot more depth than would be expected from an intro).

Comment: However, if you want to study the entity-relationship model, start with Peter Chen's papers. It's still a useful model since it's widely (though inaccurately) applied. Look into object-role modeling instead if you want to learn a more logical and complete data modeling discipline.

Comment: Thank you so much. I will definitely look into them. :)